# Rails has many through self unique validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models, Users and Coachings

One user can have many students and coaches

Code from the Users model:

```
  has_many :coachings, :foreign_key => :student_id
  has_many :coaches, :through => :coachings, :foreign_key => :coach_id
```

Code from the Coachings models:

```
belongs_to :coach, :class_name => 'User'
belongs_to :student, :class_name => 'User'
```

But this allows to add duplicate records to db (one user can have duplicate coaches or duplicate students). How to properly validate this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for a way to validate the uniqueness of the combindation of `coach_id` and `student_id`.

Try this:

**coaching.rb**

```
validates_uniqueness_of :coach_id, scope: :student_id
```

Comment: I tried this. Rails will keep asking for template ("Missing template coachings/create") and I don't want to create empty templates. But I guess, if there's no other way, I can go this way

Comment: Missing template sounds like a controller problem. How are you handling the attempted creation of invalid records?